# Logout user from Strapi (React Native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, strapi

I've been trying to logout the signed-in user from my React native app (using Strapi). Should I redirect it to any specific URL or can I delete the JWT token? If yes, please point me in the right direction of how.
Redirecting the "Logout" button to the Login page doesn't end the signed-in user's session for obvious reasons.

```
<Button
      mode="outlined"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
      style={styles.button2}
      labelStyle={{
        color: '#48b749',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlignVertical: 'center',
        textAlign: 'center',
      }}>
Logout
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're already in the right direction. `Strapi` doesn't have any `api` as such for logging out a user as logout is only done locally on the client side. This only requires you to remove the `jwt` & `username` token from your browser [`localStorage`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Let me provide you the quotes from their [strapi blog](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/blob/master/login-react/src/pages/Home.js#L28) posts below.

> We've set up two endpoints:
>
> - **login**: authenticates the user. On successful authentication, the JWT token will be available in the jwt property of the response
>   object.
> - **user**: retrieves the authenticated user's info. If the user is authenticated, the JWT token will be added to the request, allowing
>   Strapi to identify the user. Since the response object is already the
>   user info itself, we set propertyName to false.
>
> We've also disabled the logout endpoint, since logging out a user is
> only done locally and doesn't require any request to Strapi's API. The
> token is simply removed from the local storage when the user logs out.

###### Speaking of the kind of code you'll have to write, you can refer the snippet below:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let history = useHistory();

logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
  localStorage.removeItem('username');
  history.push("/sigin");
}
```

###### References:

1. [Strapi auth example in React](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/blob/master/login-react/src/pages/Home.js#L28)

Answer (score 0):

you can store logged in user details in persisted state like async storage and when user will logout then delete this details. you can do something like this.

`if(loggedInUser) { return <AuthenticatedStack /> } return <UnauthenticatedStack />`

when you delete this loggedInUser from async storage it will redirect to Unauthenticated stack or login screen.